# Javascript executing "else" only when location.reload is present?

Tags: javascript, jquery, page-refresh

I'm trying to have the page refresh if and only if there is no html (errors) returned by the $.post() function. The code works just fine when I don't have **location.reload(true);** present. When I do have it present, the ***page speed*** seems to have load speed decide if it's going to validate or not...

I tested this, and found that the code worked 80% of the time when run on a remote server, but it only worked **50% of the time** when run locally using MAMP. Why, and is there a way to fix this?

Code & everything: http://jsfiddle.net/sman591/ZHays/

Answer (score 1):

why you are having

```
var messagehtml = $('.window #message').html();
```

intead of  `var messagehtml =$('.window #message').html()`

Comment: I don't know- was trying some random things and I must not of removed it.

Comment: check the data variable using an alert or it is better if you can use firebug or chrome to debug your javascript and see whats happening.